# Two Datacenters, connectivity breaks, both continue writing, connectivity returns, sync?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, sharding, database

We have two datacenters, and are writing data to Mongo from both datacenters.  The collection is sharded and we have the primary for one shard in datacenter A and primary for the other in datacenter B.  Occasionally, **connectivity between the datacenters fails.**

**We'd like to be able to continue writing IN BOTH DATACENTERS**.  The data we're writing won't conflict - they're both just adding documents, or updating documents that won't be updated in two places.

Then, when connectivity returns (sometimes in seconds, or even minutes), we'd like the database to cope with this situation nicely and have all the data updated automatically.

Can someone please advise if this is possible?  It doesn't say much in the docs about what happens when you divide a replica set to two independent DB's, then get both to become master until you reconnect them.  What happens?  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this wouldn't work the way you already have it set up presuming that your secondaries are in the same data center as your primary.

In other words, if primary and secondaries for shard A are in data center A and primary and secondaries for shard B are in data center B, then you are already writing in both data centers.

If you now lose connectivity between the two data centers, then clients from data center A won't be able to read or write to shard B and clients in data center B won't be able to write to shard A but both data center clients will continue writing to the shard that's at the same data center as they are.

So, that's simple then - keep the majority of the replica set at the same data center and you will continue writing to that shard as long as that data center is up.

I have a feeling though that you expect that somehow magically clients from a disconnected data center will stash away their writes for the other data center's shards somewhere - that cannot happen - they cannot see the other data center.   So when connectivity returns, there is nothing for the DB to cope with (other than the fact that there were a bunch of writes that failed during disconnected phase).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to "divide a replica set" to have two primaries in the same set.

So you have two replica sets, which shards on one key using mongos as a router.
One solution is if first part of a sharding key is set to start with 'A' or 'B', which means if a new record starts with A it gets routed to the first set, and if it's B it gets routed to the 2nd set.
This is the only way you can control where mongos will try to put the data.

Connectivity problems between mongos and the different replicasets doesn't matter as long as your new entries doesn't have a sharding key which match the broken replicaset.

You could for example let the mongo client in datacenter A that writes data to always start the sharding key with A. Which means if datacenter B is down, only records with A is created.

Clients on both centers will have access to reads from both shards as long as they are up.

Mongos should run close to each client, so you will have these on both locations which will each have access to the sharding configuration

Answer (score 0):

Replica set node cannot become master unless it sees at least half of the nodes. This means that if there's no link to the datacenter where primary is, you can't write to that shard.

I can see how one can implement a home-grown solution for this. But it requires some effort.

You might also want to look at CouchDB. It's also schemaless and JSON-based and it can handle your situation well (it was basically built for situations like this).